# Wordpress advanced custom fields repeater problem with repeater fields activating same animation for all of them at once

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently at work and need help solving this problem, I've been using advanced custom fields with WordPress to make a 3x3, 200x300px image grid, when you hover over these images an overlay pops up, but the repeater is only repeating the first option for them all, so they all activate at once instead of individually. also, the images aren't showing up and can't figure out why. thank you in advance.

I've tried everything I possibly could even searching and scouring all over google, but nothing I've found seems to be even similar to my problem.

```
<html> 
<section class="portfolio">



    <div class="container">
        <?php 
        if(get_field('port_title'))
        {
            echo '<h4 class="section_seven_title">' . get_field('port_title') . '</h4>';
        }
        ?>

        <div class="row" id="section_seven_options">
            <?php 
                if(have_rows('port_selection_options')):
                while(have_rows('port_selection_options') ) : the_row();
                    $PORT_OPTION_ONE = get_sub_field('port_option_one');
                    $PORT_OPTION_TWO = get_sub_field('port_option_two');
                    $PORT_OPTION_THREE = get_sub_field('port_option_three');
            ?>

                    <div class="col-md-4"><p class="section_seven_subtitle"><?php echo $PORT_OPTION_ONE; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><p class="section_seven_subtitle"><?php echo $PORT_OPTION_TWO; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><p class="section_seven_subtitle"><?php echo $PORT_OPTION_THREE; ?></p></div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="section_seven_rowone">
                <?php 
            if(have_rows('port_picture_grid_repeater')):
            while(have_rows('port_picture_grid_repeater') ) : the_row();
                $PORT_ICONS = get_sub_field('port_icons');
                $PORT_PICTURE = get_sub_field('port_picture');
                $PORT_PICTURE_TITLE = get_sub_field('port_picture_title');
                $PORT_DESC = get_sub_field('port_desc');
        ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 col" id="section_seven_grid">
                <div class="bring_it_one">
                    <div class="outerbox_one" id="outerbox_fader_one">
                        <div class="innerbox_one">
                            <i id="icon_one"><?php echo $PORT_ICONS; ?></i>
                            <p class="people_one"><?php echo $PORT_PICTURE_TITLE; ?></p>
                            <div class="the_line_one"></div>
                            <br>
                            <p class="extra_one"><?php echo $PORT_DESC; ?></p>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>                               
                <div class="outerbox_back_one" id="image_grid_seven" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $PORT_PICTURE['url']; ?>');"></div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</html>






<style>

#image_grid_seven{width:350px; height:250px;}
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
    #image_grid_seven{width:250px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width:992px){
    #image_grid_seven{width:200px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    #image_grid_seven{width:150px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
    #image_grid_seven{width:150px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
}



@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    .portfolio{text-align: center; transition:linear 0.5s;}
}
#section_seven_options{width:50%; margin-left:25%;}



.section_seven_title{padding-bottom: 5%; text-align:center; font-weight:bolder; font-size:35px;}
.section_seven_subtitle{padding-bottom: 30%; text-align:center;}
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
    .section_seven_subtitle{display: inline; margin-right:10%}
}




#section_seven_rowone{margin-bottom:15%; margin-left:2%;}


#outerbox_fader:hover{animation: linear 0.3s porter forwards; } 
#outerbox_fader::after{opacity: 0; background-color: transparent;}




#port_change::after{opacity: 0;}
.port_overlay{background-color:#80deea; position:relative; z-index:20; height:100%; width:100%; opacity: 0;}
#port_change:hover{animation:linear 0.3s porter forwards;}
@keyframes porter{
    0%{background-color:#80deea; opacity:0.4;}
    50%{background-color:#7296d0; opacity: 0.7;}
    100%{background-color:#80deea; opacity: 0.9;}
}



/***FIRST BOX****/
#section_seven_grid{padding-top:4%;}


#outerbox_fader_one:hover{animation: linear 0.3s porter forwards; }
#outerbox_fader_one{opacity: 1; background-color: transparent;}
    .bring_it_one{ position: absolute; z-index: 50; cursor: pointer;}
    .outerbox_one{text-align: center; height:250px; width:350px; padding-top:25px; opacity:0;}
    .innerbox_one{opacity:0; text-align:center; position: relative; z-index:50}
    #icon_one{color:white;}
    .people_one{color:white; font-size:25px;}
    .the_line_one{height:5px; width:1px; background-color:white; margin-left:36%;}
    .extra_one{color:white; margin-top:0px;}
    .outerbox_back_one{background-image:url('images/porto8.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; 
    height:250px; width:350px; box-shadow:8px 10px 35px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);}
    @media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
        .the_line_one{margin-left:72px; font-size:10px; transition:linear 0.5s;} 
        .outerbox_one{width:250px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        #icon_one{font-size:30px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        .people_one{font-size:10px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
        .the_line_one{margin-left:25px; font-size:10px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        .outerbox_one{width:200px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        #icon_one{font-size:30px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        .people_one{font-size:10px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:640px){
        .the_line_one{margin-left:25px; transition:linear 0.5s; font-size:10px;}
        .outerbox_one{width:150px; height:150px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        #icon_one{font-size:30px; transition:linear 0.5s;}
        .people_one{transition:linear 0.5s; font-size:10px;}
    }
</style>




<script>
var tl_one = new TimelineMax({paused:true, delay:0.});
var outbox_one = $('.outerbox_one');
var line_one = $('.the_line_one');
var inner_one = $('.innerbox_one');
var icons_one = $('#icon_one');
var peeps_one = $('.people_one');
var another_one = $('.extra_one');

tl_one.to(outbox_one, 0.1, {opacity: 1});
tl_one.to(inner_one, 0.1, {opacity:1});
tl_one.staggerTo(line_one, 0.1, {width:"100px", opacity:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});
tl_one.staggerTo(icons_one, 0.1, {y: -5, opacity:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});
tl_one.staggerTo(peeps_one, 0.1, {y:10, opacity:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});
tl_one.staggerTo(another_one, 0.1, {y:-10, opacity:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});


function over_one(){
  tl_one.play();}
function out_one(){
  tl_one.reverse();}

outbox_one.hover(over_one, out_one);
</script>
```

i expected them to work indiviually (hover over a specific one and just run the animation for that one alone) not all of them at once

Comment: HI swairmi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend to shrink your code to the relevant parts as right now it's a bit bloated. 
Regarding your problem: your script at the bottom of the code targets elements based on their class names. As you create the elements in a while-loop and assign each one the same classes, the effects are all called on the same elements. You need to find the closest elements when a hover happened using i.e. jQuery's [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) functionality to only fire it on the right element.